# explanation of MIPS ldc1 instruction 1

Tags: mips

I've a question about the instruction lwc1.
According to my understanding, this instruction allow to get value from a memory address. For example  if $t0 is equal to 2. When I execute this instruction ldc1 $f0, 0($t0). Thus, $f0 us equal to 2. Is it correct? I've tried to simulate it with mars simulator but no success

Comment: _"For example if $t0 is equal to 2. When I execute this instruction ... $f0 is equal to 2  Is it correct?"_ No. `ldc1` loads a 64-bit floating point value from memory. In your example, the address in memory to load the value from is given in register `$t0`. The value 2 is unlikely to be a valid address for your program to read from.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. This addressing mode is then equal to an indirect addressing like in C a pointer of pointer.